# Cannot figure out if bounty was already created on a question

Tags: discussion, bug, bounty

I have this existing question:
[Git metadata - is there a way to add git metadata that is independent of each branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51794791/git-metadata-is-there-a-way-to-add-git-metadata-that-is-independent-of-each-br)

I am trying to figure out if a bounty was ever created on it? I want to create a bounty and there is no "bounty" button that I can see on the page.

Here is my "proof" of no "start a bounty" button beneath "add a comment":

> [image]

Comment: I see a “start a bounty” right beneath “add a comment”.

Comment: yeah weird, I don't see that button on that question, I see "start a bounty" on my other questions though. I will add a screenshot...

Comment: I don't see anything on [the timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/51794791/timeline)

Comment: and just FYI if I click "show 1 more comment" nooo "start a bounty" does NOT appear ok :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In your [bounties tab](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1223975/alexander-mills?tab=bounties&sort=active) I can see that you already have three bounties active. To quote the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty):

> Users may only have three active bounties at any given time.

Comment: ah yes, surely that's it, that's a semi-annoying feature, second or third time that's happened to me, always catches me by surprise and take me awhile to figure out what's going on. IMO the button should NOT disappear, what should happen is if you click it, it tells you that you are "out of bounties"...

Comment: @AlexanderMills It would certainly be more consistent with how SO's UI is designed in general. (E.g. voting buttons present where you can't vote, etc). I agree it would be an improvement.

Comment: @yivi Small difference is that, for example, the vote buttons are always present but the bounty button only after the question is X days old.

Comment: @AndréKool Yet another inconsistency that should be fixed as well, IMO. I'd write a FR, but I'm lazy.

Comment: how do I write a Feature Request for this one?

Comment: @AlexanderMills Post a new question, and tag it "feature-request". Check the tag [tag guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/feature-request/info) to see what's required in such a question, and search first to see if it hasn't been suggested yet.